# Error while installing Cordova

Tags: networking, software-installation, npm, ubuntu-for-android

I am getting this error while installing Cordova:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED*
npm ERR!     at SecurePair. (tls.js:1370:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write 
(_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
```

Please tell the cause of this error and how I can remove it.

Comment: I already installed git and npm. Still causing error (CERT_UNTRUSTED).

Comment: did you try to disable it `npm config set strict-ssl false` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of npm is not up to date, so you cannot install Cordova until you successfully update it. After your npm is updated to npm 6.1.0 Cordova can be installed successfully. The best way to update npm is to install the *node* snap package which has npm bundled with it, and then update npm with `sudo npm i npm`.

---

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v11.5.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=10/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |

Comment: i type npm list yarn and  get /home/bhaskar/Downloads
└── (empty)   . after that i  type npm update yarn and  npm -v  . and show the same version .

Comment: @Bhaskararya That's OK and also expected. yarn has nothing to do with Cordova. I just used the yarn package as an example of how npm works.

Comment: so how to update my npm . i want to install cordova very badly. thanks for help me .

Comment: Run `sudo npm i npm` to update npm to the latest version.

Comment: it not working either giving same error. no matter whether i try to update with npm i npm or npm install --save latest-version. i uninstall all the packages(git,nodjs,npm) and reinstall that not work either.

Comment: Sorry, it worked in my computer. Snap packages are supposed to be Ubuntu version independent. Do you still get the same `Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED` error message?

Comment: any other paltform where i can work on app development and easy to install.

Comment: Ubuntu is the easiest to work with platform for development that I've found, especially if you sandbox everything dodgy.